# How to make a div have a fixed size?

Tags: css, html, fixed

I made a webpage, on which clicking the button 30px changes the font inside the `div`.

I have a `ul` inside it with the buttons. When I change the font size, the `div` expands and the `nav` buttons move with it as well.

How do I make it so it stays fixed but the fonts can still change.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Try the following css:

```css
#innerbox
{
   width:250px; /* or whatever width you want. */
   max-width:250px; /* or whatever width you want. */
   display: inline-block;
}
```

This makes the div take as little space as possible, and its width is defined by the css.

## Expanded answer

To make the buttons fixed widths do the following :

```css
#innerbox input
{
   width:150px; /* or whatever width you want. */
   max-width:150px; /* or whatever width you want. */
}
```

However, you should be aware that as the size of the text changes, so does the space needed to display it.  As such, it's natural that the containers need to expand.  You should perhaps review what you are trying to do; and maybe have some predefined classes that you alter on the fly using javascript to ensure the content placement is perfect.

Comment: This worked for the div that changes the font but now my stupid buttons are still floating :S

Comment: @MikeCollins I have expanded my answer.  Altering the size of the text will make the text flow out of the buttons if they are fixed width - some browsers may still expand them. I think you need to rethink your strategy for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: ok, but if I don't know what width I want? I want to remain fix width after first render

Comment: @Alex that is beyond the scope of the original question.  Please open a new question as what you are aiming to do differs from the OP.

Answer (score 1):

you can give it a `max-height` and `max-width` in your `.css`

```css
.fontpixel{
  max-width:200px; 
  max-height:200px;
}
```

in addition to your height and width properties

Comment: Okay so it works but now the buttons move all over is there a way to make it stay in its spot?

Answer (score 0):

Thats the natural behavior of the buttons. You could try putting a max-width/max-height on the parent container, but I'm not sure if that would do it.

```
max-width:something px;
max-height:something px;
```

The other option would be to use the devlopr tools and see if you can remove the natural padding.

```
padding: 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div>
  <img src="whatever it is" class="image-crop">
</div>

 /*mobile code*/
    .image-crop{
      width:100%;
      max-height: auto;
     }
    /*desktop code*/

  @media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
    .image-crop{
       width:100%;
       max-height: 140px;
      }
```

Answer (score -3):

Use this style

```
<div class="form-control"
     style="height:100px;
     width:55%;
     overflow:hidden;
     cursor:pointer">
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<div class="ai">a b c d e f</div> // something like ~100px
<div class="ai">a b c d e</div> // ~80
<div class="ai">a b c d</div> // ~60 

<script>

function _reWidthAll_div(classname) {

var _maxwidth = 0;

    $(classname).each(function(){

    var _width = $(this).width();

    _maxwidth = (_width >= _maxwidth) ? _width : _maxwidth; // define max width
    });    

$(classname).width(_maxwidth); // return all div same width

}

_reWidthAll_div('.ai');

</script>
```

Comment: Try to explain your  solution.

Comment: What is this $ stuff? Can someone write a readable replacement please?

Comment: this is more easy with jquery. i dont want to use document.getElementsByClassName