# How to prevent div container being resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using div container as a drop-able element, so I am adding buttons elements dynamically in to this div container. Div size is resizing if I am adding buttons beyond its size how to avoid this?

Note: This issue occurs in Firefox only

[sample:fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpqz01ct/1/)

```
#divContainer{
    width:100%;
    height:40%;
    overflow:auto;
    border:1px solid;
    display:inline-block;
}
#click{
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
}
table{
    border:1px solid;
}
body{
    height:1000px;
}
```

//html

```
<button id="click">ClickME</button>
<table style="width:20%; height:30%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="divContainer">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

//script

```
 $(function () {

        $("#click").on("click", function () {

            $("#divContainer").append($("#click").clone());
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please provide more parts of your code, ideally a jsFiddle demo that shows your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526071/how-to-make-a-div-have-a-fixed-size

Comment: @Aziz: https://jsfiddle.net/cpqz01ct/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
#divcontainer
{
max-width: 40%;
max-height: 30%;
overflow:auto;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: "Not sure" is a _terrible_ way to start out your answer. If you have the heart to go out and answer broad questions, include multiple solutions so _at least_ one of them helps the OP. Just some advice!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using table, table elements doesn't goes well in `%` value in different browsers, they adjust their width/height according to the content. So its better you go with `max-width` and `min-width` value (that's also in pixels), so that cross-browsers don't create any mess for your design-

Try below css code:

```
#divContainer{
    width:100%;
    min-height:100px;
    height:40%;
    max-height:100px;
    overflow:auto;
    border:1px solid;
    display:inline-block;
}
#click{
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
}
table{
    border:1px solid;
}
body{
    height:1000px;
}
```

Updated fiddle link- 
https://jsfiddle.net/cpqz01ct/3/

Comment: Is any other way to preventing from this problem without using "min-height"?

Comment: Yes, you can instead of using `table`, go for CSS property `display:table;` and `display:table-cell` on `div` element, then can use `postion:absolute` to make height work in `%` since `div` elements does not resize automatically like `table`.

Comment: For little experiment with your layout, you can also check this link-
https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: I have checked with your previous comment, not working. This problem happens only in Firefox browser.