# Div class gets bigger

Tags: html, css

I'm really really new to coding and I've got a problem with HTMl.
I've made two inputs for username and password, but when I fill in something, the div just gets bigger?!
I really dont know how this happens but it should be static and not change the size.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.  For starters, please include a [mcve] to your question. Otherwise, it might take a lot more time and a heap of guessing to figure *exactly* where the issue lies.

Comment: This question has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526071/how-to-make-a-div-have-a-fixed-size

Comment: Go to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526071/how-to-make-a-div-have-a-fixed-size

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a div have a fixed size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526071/how-to-make-a-div-have-a-fixed-size)

Answer (score 0):

If you share your code, it would be easier to see what the problem is.

One way to set the width of a div element to a precise width is to specify what the width should be in your CSS file or inline like `<input style="width:200px;" type="text">`